# AVLTree Insert Item Infinite Loop

Tags: c#, avl-tree

I have an issue with my application.

Using the debugger I've found that my application is stuck in an infinite loop. I have attached an image to demonstrate the error which occurs when I try to execute the program.

[When executed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHm7z.png)

However, when debugging I've come to the conclusion this is an issue with either my `CompareTo`method or my `InsertItem` method in my AVLTree class.

The program appears to loop around the following line of codes-

In my `Country` class-

```
    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        Country temp = (Country)obj;


        return name.CompareTo(temp.name);

    }
```

And in my `AVLTree` class (doesn't go past the code I have attached)-

```
  private void insertItem(T item, ref Node<T> tree)
        {
            if (tree == null)
            {
                tree = new Node<T>(item);
            }
            else if (item.CompareTo(tree.Data) < 0)
            {
                insertItem(item, ref tree.Left);
            }
```

I am reading in data from a CSV file, however, this occurs when the application reads in the fourth entry in the CSV File.

I can insert the following countries - USA, Canada, Brazil but Chile (the next record) appears to run into this issue. I was wondering what the problem could be?

I am inserting this data with this piece of code:

```
avlTree.InsertItem(new Country(columns[0], float.Parse(columns[1]), float.Parse(columns[2]), float.Parse(columns[3]), Int32.Parse(columns[4]), tradingPartners));
```

I have the loop to get the trading partners and the code to read in the file as well, just cannot seem to get out of this loop. Where could the issue lie?

I have the following classes-

```
AVLTree
BSTree
BinTree
Country
Node
Form
Program
```

Thank you for your time.

UPDATE - My whole  `Country` class where my `CompareTo` method is-

```
private string name;
private float GDP;
private float inflation;
private float tradeBal;
private int HDI;
public LinkedList<String> tradingPartners;
public string x;

public Country()
{

}
public Country(string name, float GDP, float inflation, float tradeBal, int HDI, LinkedList<String> tradingPartners)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.GDP = GDP;
    this.inflation = inflation;
    this.tradeBal = tradeBal;
    this.HDI = HDI;
    this.tradingPartners = tradingPartners;
}
public string CountryName
{
    get { return name; }
    set { name = value; }
}

public float GDPGrowth
{
    get { return GDP; }
    set { GDP = value; }
}

public float Inflation
{
    get { return inflation; }
    set { inflation = value; }
}

public float TradeBalance
{
    get { return tradeBal; }
    set { tradeBal = value; }
}

public int HDIRank
{
    get { return HDI; }
    set { HDI = value; }
}


public LinkedList<String> TradingPartners
    {
        get { return tradingPartners; }
        set { tradingPartners = value; }
    }




public int CompareTo(object obj)
{
    Country temp = (Country)obj;


    return name.CompareTo(temp.name);

}

public override string ToString()
{
    foreach (string y in TradingPartners)
    {
        x += y + ", ";
    }

    return name + ". " + GDP + ", " + inflation + ", " + tradeBal + ", " + HDI + "[ " + x + " ]";
}
```

I hope this can be of help, I don't think it's my AVLTree as I used to once before and no issues arised. I forgot to add, the code continuously loops back and forth between my `CompareTo` and my `insertItem` method (up to where I've pasted it in, will not go further than that).

Comment: In `CompareTo` there is a reference to `name`; please show the entire class that `CompareTo` is contained in. It looks as if `CompareTo` occurs in some infinite recursion. It is also possible that the tree contains a cycle by containing a circular reference.

Comment: There's not enough information here. *Step through your code in the debugger* and see exactly where it's looping. Assuming `name` in your `Country` class is a string, there is no reason why your `CompareTo` should be the problem.

Comment: And why are you using the `ref` keyword in `insertItem`?

Comment: @MattBurland I'm passing by `ref` I used it once before in a portfolio we were tasked with and we got instructed to use the `ref` keyword so I'm reusing the portfolio tasks to produce this assignment.

Comment: @MattBurland It's looping between both the `CompareTo` and the `insertItem` method up to where I've pasted it. It continuously goes back and forth.

Comment: Well don't use it if you don't understand [what it does](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx). There are very few situations that actually require it.

Comment: @MattBurland he has to use it because if he makes a change to a different object within the tree hierarchy he needs to updated all the other references hence it's necessary to use ref.

Comment: ImTheOneWhoCodes and @OusmaneMahyDiaw; I have moved this conversation [to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136082/discussion-on-question-by-imtheonewhocodes-avltree-insert-item-infinite-loop). There you can hold a semi-private conversation, if you would like to.